# Fingerprint Sensor not working in Acer Swift 3 SF315-41

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I cannot find fingerprint option in settings, I've also tried installing **Fingerprint GUI**. But it is saying no fingerprint scanner detected.

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint scanner, an Elan Microelectronics reader, is not yet supported. If the device is not supported, the program can't detect it.